# Spring websocket (STOMP) registration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Good day! I have a simple chat with Spring websocket and STOMP.
In some examples I have seen authentication with spring-security-web and spring-security-config - something like

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
 auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
}
```

But the problem is - withUser("user") is hardcoded and  method is called at whole system start up - what if I wand a dynamic user registration?

So the questions are:

1) How can I make dynamic registration? Something like :

```
@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/chat", "/registration").withSockJS();
}
```

And do some @MessageMapping("/registration") ? and inside parce the message with registration data? I quess there is a better way...

2) After user registration from question 1 - how can I dynamically check if user is registered when he connects to web socket and prevent subscribing to my endpoints and sending messages if he is not?

Comment: By not using in-memory authentication but by using a proper database and hook that up to Spring Security.

Comment: M. Deinum, can you point me to right direction - where can I read about it? And by the way - this is answer for both questions or for one only?

Comment: For both. Just write the user registration as you normally would and let Spring Security use those tables to retrieve the users. Where would you read about such a thing, how about the [Spring Security guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/)?